# OpenLayers Timeline implement history marker player with time

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to implement OpenLayers TimeLine with [openlayers-timeline](https://github.com/volpino/openlayers-timeline)

There are no working samples since GEOJSON files are missing [Missing GEOJSON](http://toolserver.org/%7Esonet/api_geojson.php?article=OpenLayers&callback=?).

I have marker history as below;

```
Name: "marker1",
Lat: -41.310110,
Lng: 174.786132,
Start: 2021-01-10 10:20:00
End: 2021-01-10 10:48:00
Label: "Marker description"
```

- When I select a date range, the slider can be played or manually dragged.
- While the slider is playing, markers should appear on Start-time
  and disappear on End-time.
- Slider time gap should be adjusted and the default is 5 mins.

I think, if I have a sample geojson file for this repo, I can implement this.
Hope anyone got this file.

Comment: You will probably need to host your own copy of the php https://github.com/volpino/toolserver-scripts/blob/master/php/api_geojson.php

Comment: I am looking for a working sample GeoJason file for the above repo. Then I can make my own PHP or whatever

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is returning Point features with `when` and `country` properties.  `when` is seconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and `country` is a country name string.  Importing the KML example, extracting time from the name and adding an appropriate country name would produce this GeoJSON

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.718994140625,-52.32600021362305,0]},"properties":{"when":1315512711,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.72000122070312,-52.33000183105469,0]},"properties":{"when":1315512682,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.72000122070312,-52.327999114990234,0]},"properties":{"when":1315510733,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.70399475097656,-52.31800079345703,0]},"properties":{"when":1315506779,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.7270050048828,-52.29899978637695,0]},"properties":{"when":1315506473,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.7100067138672,-52.32099914550781,0]},"properties":{"when":1315506473,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.6790008544922,-52.316001892089844,0]},"properties":{"when":1315504955,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.66200256347656,-52.31999969482422,0]},"properties":{"when":1315481382,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.64300537109375,-52.319000244140625,0]},"properties":{"when":1315477593,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.63999938964844,-52.31800079345703,0]},"properties":{"when":1315477570,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.63800048828125,-52.31800079345703,0]},"properties":{"when":1315475739,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.62600708007812,-52.31999969482422,0]},"properties":{"when":1315471462,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.61900329589844,-52.31700134277344,0]},"properties":{"when":1315471394,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.625,-52.31700134277344,0]},"properties":{"when":1315471371,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.61599731445312,-52.31700134277344,0]},"properties":{"when":1315469589,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.51699829101562,-52.31399917602539,0]},"properties":{"when":1315427745,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.51100158691406,-52.314998626708984,0]},"properties":{"when":1315427022,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.5030059814453,-52.3120002746582,0]},"properties":{"when":1315421080,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.5050048828125,-52.30699920654297,0]},"properties":{"when":1315419842,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.4429931640625,-52.31100082397461,0]},"properties":{"when":1315396478,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.43299865722656,-52.310001373291016,0]},"properties":{"when":1315393484,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.41099548339844,-52.30500030517578,0]},"properties":{"when":1315392223,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.42599487304688,-52.29899978637695,0]},"properties":{"when":1315391841,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.42799377441406,-52.297000885009766,0]},"properties":{"when":1315390765,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.41700744628906,-52.29100036621094,0]},"properties":{"when":1315386400,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.39700317382812,-52.292999267578125,0]},"properties":{"when":1315385693,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.40199279785156,-52.29100036621094,0]},"properties":{"when":1315384817,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.25999450683594,-52.24800109863281,0]},"properties":{"when":1315342513,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.26199340820312,-52.249000549316406,0]},"properties":{"when":1315341373,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.26300048828125,-52.24700164794922,0]},"properties":{"when":1315340820,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.26600646972656,-52.23899841308594,0]},"properties":{"when":1315336434,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.25399780273438,-52.23899841308594,0]},"properties":{"when":1315335458,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.25,-52.237998962402344,0]},"properties":{"when":1315334779,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.27000427246094,-52.141998291015625,0]},"properties":{"when":1315307675,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.2760009765625,-52.13800048828125,0]},"properties":{"when":1315307239,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.25,-52.138999938964844,0]},"properties":{"when":1315305709,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.2550048828125,-52.13600158691406,0]},"properties":{"when":1315305551,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.25599670410156,-52.11800003051758,0]},"properties":{"when":1315301157,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.2480010986328,-52.1150016784668,0]},"properties":{"when":1315300025,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.24200439453125,-52.1150016784668,0]},"properties":{"when":1315299797,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.95899963378906,-52.03900146484375,0]},"properties":{"when":1315255646,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.93600463867188,-52.013999938964844,0]},"properties":{"when":1315251464,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.92999267578125,-52.007999420166016,0]},"properties":{"when":1315249862,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.92100524902344,-52.00600051879883,0]},"properties":{"when":1315249566,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.87600708007812,-51.981998443603516,0]},"properties":{"when":1315245883,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.875,-51.90599822998047,0]},"properties":{"when":1315221892,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.8769989013672,-51.902000427246094,0]},"properties":{"when":1315221782,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.86199951171875,-51.89799880981445,0]},"properties":{"when":1315220803,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.81199645996094,-51.88999938964844,0]},"properties":{"when":1315214766,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.7969970703125,-51.89099884033203,0]},"properties":{"when":1315214257,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.79800415039062,-51.89099884033203,0]},"properties":{"when":1315214257,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.8470001220703,-51.87200164794922,0]},"properties":{"when":1315210288,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.60899353027344,-51.74599838256836,0]},"properties":{"when":1315166218,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.5850067138672,-51.72700119018555,0]},"properties":{"when":1315164834,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.60899353027344,-51.731998443603516,0]},"properties":{"when":1315163949,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.56199645996094,-51.64799880981445,0]},"properties":{"when":1315136861,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.54600524902344,-51.67100143432617,0]},"properties":{"when":1315136097,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.51199340820312,-51.65299987792969,0]},"properties":{"when":1315131072,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.49899291992188,-51.65800094604492,0]},"properties":{"when":1315129830,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.50599670410156,-51.65599822998047,0]},"properties":{"when":1315128660,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.45899963378906,-51.665000915527344,0]},"properties":{"when":1315124908,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.4320068359375,-51.67599868774414,0]},"properties":{"when":1315123709,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.57000732421875,-50.553001403808594,0]},"properties":{"when":1315045777,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.5399932861328,-50.50899887084961,0]},"properties":{"when":1315044747,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.5679931640625,-50.4379997253418,0]},"properties":{"when":1315043062,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.5399932861328,-50.29600143432617,0]},"properties":{"when":1315038775,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.5189971923828,-50.22700119018555,0]},"properties":{"when":1315036923,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[169.9759979248047,-49.367000579833984,0]},"properties":{"when":1314960782,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.04299926757812,-49.369998931884766,0]},"properties":{"when":1314957240,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.08700561523438,-49.361000061035156,0]},"properties":{"when":1314953775,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.10800170898438,-49.3650016784668,0]},"properties":{"when":1314951255,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.38600158691406,-49.14799880981445,0]},"properties":{"when":1314910676,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.73699951171875,-48.152000427246094,0]},"properties":{"when":1314875655,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.8280029296875,-47.959999084472656,0]},"properties":{"when":1314869648,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[170.76300048828125,-47.95600128173828,0]},"properties":{"when":1314868944,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[172.6479949951172,-44.77399826049805,0]},"properties":{"when":1314779948,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[173.9770050048828,-42.75699996948242,0]},"properties":{"when":1314735289,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[173.8820037841797,-42.65700149536133,0]},"properties":{"when":1314733771,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.0709991455078,-42.49300003051758,0]},"properties":{"when":1314729298,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.52499389648438,-41.064998626708984,0]},"properties":{"when":1314699517,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.5290069580078,-41.119998931884766,0]},"properties":{"when":1314649216,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.47999572753906,-41.194000244140625,0]},"properties":{"when":1314614128,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.52099609375,-41.3129997253418,0]},"properties":{"when":1314608401,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.52999877929688,-41.32600021362305,0]},"properties":{"when":1314608131,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.3470001220703,-41.36899948120117,0]},"properties":{"when":1314607816,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.78399658203125,-41.31999969482422,0]},"properties":{"when":1314547832,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.7100067138672,-41.30400085449219,0]},"properties":{"when":1314540587,"country":"New Zealand"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[174.78700256347656,-41.319000244140625,0]},"properties":{"when":1314522868,"country":"New Zealand"}}]}
```